# Convert milliseconds to Date in SQL Server for date after 01/01/2040

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert milliseconds to date in SQL Server for a date after 01/01/2040.

I tried this, but I'm getting an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ
(
    [ExpirationDate] float
);
    
INSERT INTO XYZ ([ExpirationDate])
VALUES
    (1301598290687),
    (2240542800000),--> this is 01/01/2040
    (2144034000000);    

SELECT
    DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
            CAST(ExpirationDate AS bigint) % 1000, 
    DATEADD(SECOND, CAST(ExpirationDate AS bigint) / 1000, '19700101'))
FROM
    XYZ
```

Also tried

```
SELECT CAST(ExpirationDate AS DATETIME) FROM XYZ
```

but that's not working either.

See this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c03a31832364b5a636f47eb66034c19

Looking for Date output like if we pass `2240542800000` ms as value then output should be date 01/01/2040

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: `date` is a specific type, not a float. Don't use floats to store dates. Otherwise, nobody will be able to use that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to split the problem into date and time pieces:

```
select (DATEADD(DAY, 
                FLOOR(ExpirationDate / (24*60*60*1000.0) ), 
                '19700101') +
        DATEADD(MILLISECOND, CONVERT(bigint, ExpirationDate) % (24*60*60*1000), 0)
       )
from XYZ
```